# React: How to move function outside of component body

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have function which is placed in `render(){}`

Need to move that function from render.

But When I move it inside of `class` body, get the errror when calling that function.

**Code reproduction:**

This is function `outherElementType`

```
render() {
    const outerElementType = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <div ref={ref} onClick={(e) => this.handleSelectDoc(e)} {...props} role="button" />
    ));
```

This is where `outherElementType` is passed:

```
         <AutoSizer>
            {({ height }) => (
              <List
                itemData={this.props.data}
                itemSize={150}
                outerElementType={outerElementType}
              >
                {NewsRenderer}
              </List>
            )}
          </AutoSizer>
```

I tried to move `outherElementType` to outside of component, but problem is this `this.handleSelectDoc(e)` function which is passed from cmponent body to this function.

```
    const outerElementType = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <div ref={ref} onClick={(e) => this.handleSelectDoc(e)} {...props} role="button" />
    ));
```

Comment: What is the error you get? May you put that in your question?

Comment: Why you want to move that function outside? If you want the component smaller you can put `handleSelectDoc` as parameter to the function, but that function will need to return outerElementType, so it can be create with onClick event, so it will be the same, the function will need to be create in component. If you want to optimize then you can create the function in constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move you component outside of `render` but still inside the `class component` then you need to use the `this` keyword to refer to the "new function" you created

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  outerElementType = forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <div ref={ref} onClick={(e) => this.handleSelectDoc(e)} {...props} role="button" />
  ));

  render() {
    return <AutoSizer>
    {({ height }) => (
      <List
        itemData={this.props.data}
        itemSize={150}
        outerElementType={this.outerElementType}
      >
        {NewsRenderer}
      </List>
    )}
    </AutoSizer>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short version:** Any method/object declared inside a class context has to be accessed using the `this` keyword. Therefore, the code should work by writing `this.outerElementType` instead of just `outerElementType`.

```
<AutoSizer>
      {({ height }) => (
        <List
          itemData={this.props.data}
          itemSize={150}
          outerElementType={this.outerElementType}
        >
          {NewsRenderer}
        </List>
      )}
</AutoSizer>
```

---

**Long version:** ES6 or Javascript in general has a way of preprocessing classes and constructors.

Consider this class.

```
class Example {
    name = 'My Name';
    email = 'email@example.com'

    printHello = function(){
       console.log('hello')
    }
}
```

Now both variables `name` and `email` as well the function `printHello` have been declared directly inside context of the class. Javascript will process the code as follows.

```
class Example {
    constructor(){
        name = 'My Name';
        email = 'email@example.com'

        printHello = function(){
           console.log('hello')
        }
    }
}
```

Looking at this example, you can see that these objects are declared as attributes and methods of the class itself rather than independent variables. Therefore, must be accessed by specifying `this` to signify that you're calling a method that belongs to the class.

If you were to declare an object or function outside of the class, you'd be able to access them directly without using `this` since they are not processed to be an attribute of the class.